# Mysql Fulltext Natural Language which recognizes word aliases

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, alias

I have implemented a Mysql Fulltext Natural Language search on a table.  It is working well, but I now need to improve the search to be able to recognize word aliases. I.E digits as words, compound words and other misc equivalent words. How do I do this?

Here are some examples of search terms which need to be considered aliases of each other:

**Digits & their word equivalents**

1 => one

2 => two

1000 => one thousand

**Compound words**

racecar => race car

sunbeam => sun beam

**Misc**

& => and

vs => versus

Comment: Why don't do replacements in application? In SQL that would be painful

Comment: I as thinking about that, but implementing all the possible replacements myself will be a mission, especially when it comes to multi-language.  I am hoping for an external solution that will handle all of this.